# How does Windows Small Business Server 2003 count users toward the 75 user limit?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we need CALs for our clients if we store their user accounts for third party apps in Active Directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/64238/do-we-need-cals-for-our-clients-if-we-store-their-user-accounts-for-third-party-a)

We are considering storing accounts for our third party FTP server in Active Directory. These users are not the normal users (not employees) but rather external users (our clients). Do these user accounts count towards the 75 users limit on Windows Small Business Server 2003?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on actual "connections established" not the actual user count in AD.  So you could hold thousands of actual users in AD as long as no more than 75 users try to establish authentication (and stay connected) to the SBS server at any given time.

So yes, you could store the accounts in AD, as long as you are certain that the FTP server won't get used by a ton of "user accounts" at any given time.

Answer (score -2):

If the accounts are in AD, they are counted. If your third party tool stores usernames/passwords internally, they won't be counted against the 75 account limit.

Comment: This is actually incorrect Josh.